# Camera keeps opening onViewDidAppear..how can I stop this?

Tags: objective-c

I have an app with a camera. The user presses a button and the view changes to the camera view.

In the cameraView, I put the pickerControl in the viewDidLoad.

When the view appears, the camera opens and allows the user to take a picture. When done, the user can choose to keep the photo and if he does, the camera view dismisses and in that moment, I can see the picture I've taken in the image viws I created but the camera keeps opening up.

I think it's because I have my pickerControl in my viewDidLoad and every time the camera dismisses, because of that, it repeatedly keeps opening the camera. Is there any way around this? 
Here is my cameraViewController that loads when the user selects the camera option

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
     {



          [super viewDidLoad];
     }


      //  When the view appears, the camera will turn on

   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

       {

     //      Initialize the picker control
          UIImagePickerController *pickerControl = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

     //          If all's good, start up the camera
              if ((pickerControl != nil)&&(picHolder == nil))
              {
                pickerControl.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                pickerControl.delegate = self;
                pickerControl.allowsEditing = true;

               }
     //              Camera turns on


            [self presentViewController:pickerControl animated:true completion:nil];


}
```

Im not sure how to prevent the view from loading every time when that is what opens the camera in the first place.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a BOOL ivar to your class. Some pseudocode below

```
YourController {
  BOOL didShow;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  if (!didShow) {
    // present the UIImagePickerController
  }
  didShow = YES;
}
```

Comment: Eugene, that worked perfectly! Could you quickly elaborate on what that does? (BOOL didShow;) I've never seen it before? Thanks again!

Comment: Basically, you're setting up a `BOOL` variable that could've had any other name, that simply checks whether `-viewDidAppear:` was called at least once. If it wasn't `if (!didShow)` - you're presenting user with  image picker